# Strange result for a master's thesis in bibliography

Tags: biber, spanish

The attached MWE show the problem. The cited master's thesis is labelled as "Tesis de mtría", which should be rendered as "Tesis de maestría" in Spanish (the principal language of the document).

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MastersThesis{noguera21:_tesis,
  language =     {spanish},
  author =   {Noguera, Norberto},
  title =    {Irrelevante en extremo},
  school =   {U. de la Vida},
  year =     2021
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is using the abbreviated string. I think there is a better way to select the non-abbreviated version, but I don't know how. The brute-force way is to declare only one version with `\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{mathesis = {Tesis de maestr\'{\i}a}}`.

Comment: Random observation—I was intrigued by someone writing their thesis at the Charles University in Slovak which seemed unlikely to me and in the process of looking to see if this was really the case (it is!), I also turned up that Pavel Kropitz's work was not a Master's Thesis, but rather a Bachelor's Thesis: https://dspace.cuni.cz/handle/20.500.11956/37142

Comment: @DonHosek, many thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, yes, that fixes it. Strange use of an abbreviation, in any case (for shaving off three letters?!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All `biblatex` bibstrings as defined in the `.lbx` file come in two forms: A long version and a short version.

You can globally (i.e. for all bibstrings printed by `biblatex`) choose whether you want the long or short form with the `abbreviate` option, whose pre-set value is `true`.

`spanish.lbx` has

```
mathesis = {{Tesis de maestr\'{\i}a}{Tesis de mtr\'{\i}a\adddot}},
```

If you want "Tesis de maestría", you could set `abbreviate=false`, but that affects all strings printed by `biblatex`, so you would also see "página" instead of "pág.", which might be a bit much

```
\documentclass[english, spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MastersThesis{kropitz10:_problem_busy_beaver,
  REALlanguage = {slovak},
  language     = {czech},
  author       = {Kropitz, Pavel},
  title        = {Problém Busy Beaver},
  school       = {Charles University},
  year         = 2010,
  address      = {Prague},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[30]{kropitz10:_problem_busy_beaver}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1, página 30]//Pavel Kropitz. “Problém Busy Beaver”. Checo. Tesis de maestría. Prague: Charles University, 2010.]

So it is probably easier to just redefine the bibstring for master thesis. When you redefine bibstrings in the preamble of your `.tex` document, `biblatex` will use the same text for long and short form, so we could say

```
\documentclass[english, spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  mathesis = {Tesis de maestría},
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MastersThesis{kropitz10:_problem_busy_beaver,
  REALlanguage = {slovak},
  language     = {czech},
  author       = {Kropitz, Pavel},
  title        = {Problém Busy Beaver},
  school       = {Charles University},
  year         = 2010,
  address      = {Prague},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[30]{kropitz10:_problem_busy_beaver}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

to get

[image: Lorem [1, pág. 30]//Pavel Kropitz. “Problém Busy Beaver”. Checo. Tesis de maestría. Prague: Charles University, 2010.]